# Setting up languages in emacs

Tags: emacs

So i started working with emacs as a programming editor, well i was wondering how you set the language path for a language? Im using python and its giving a error saying searching for directory: no such file or directory,python.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by this. Are you talking about syntax highlighting (`python-mode`) or an actual python interpreter?

Comment: Do you have python properly installed and in your path? If you type `python` into a terminal, does it do anything?

Comment: yes, i do have python installed, and i want the interpreter so i can also have a output to my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general mechanism, it depends upon the specific language support mode.

For Python, there is the variable `python-python-command`. It's default value is just `python`, but if that doesn't work on your system, you can set it to a path (e.g. with `M-x customize-variable`).

You can also change the python command without changing the configuration by invoking `run-python` with a prefix, i.e. `C-u M-x run-python`.

Comment: sorry it has been a while, im still working with setting it up, and is their anyway i can make the interpreter interact with a specific file, so i could just type "main()" or the name of a function and it will output that? thanks

Comment: `C-c C-l` is bound to `python-load-file` in a Python interpreter buffer. In a Python file buffer, `C-c C-c` is bound to `python-send-buffer` which will send the current buffer to the interpreter.

Comment: hey, sorry its been a while again, but are you aware as to how to set the python path in emacs 24? when ever i do run-python i get the same error as before, but i cant actually link c:/Python27/python.exe to my emacs, thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not yet using Emacs 24, but I took a look at the source. This suggests the variable is now called just `python-command`: http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1516